# Local storage setup in Carrierwave (development environment) images are not rendering well

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave

Why am I seeing images like these...

http://i46.tinypic.com/16bn0js.png

The images are stored in my tmp/uploads folder:

Btw, I put this condition in my ads_uploader.rb

```
       if Rails.env.production?
    CarrierWave.configure do |config|
      config.storage :fog
      def store_dir
      "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
      end

      def cache_dir
      "#{Rails.root}/tmp/uploads"
      end
    end
  end


  if Rails.env.development?

    CarrierWave.configure do |config|
      config.root = Rails.root
      config.storage :file

      def
      store_dir
        "#{Rails.root}/tmp/uploads"

      end

      #I am not sure about this one ~SS
      def cache_dir
        "#{Rails.root}/tmp/uploads"
      end
    end


  end
```

The upload process is successful in development env. The file is stored in tmp/uploads directory.

But while viewing it in view.

ads.html.haml:

The images are not showing. (See the image url above)

Please help. Did i miss something like url or what?

Answer (score 4):

Try

```
def store_dir
  "#{Rails.root}/public/uploads"
end
```

"/tmp"  doesn't has permission to serve asset directly,move to public and check it out